# Update a field when the other is filled on Django

Tags: python, django

Here is the fields in my model :

```
PAID = 'PG'
UNPAID = 'UN'
OVERDUE = 'OV'
status_CHOICE = [
    (PAID, 'Pago'),
    (UNPAID, 'Aberto'),
    (OVERDUE, 'Vencido')
]
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, choices=status_CHOICE)
subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

I need the `status` field filled with `status_CHOICE` when change the subtotal field is equal to zero, and equal to date `OVERDUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the save method to capture the logic you want

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #logic here
        if self.subtotal == ?:
            self.status == ?
        ....
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # finally call the save method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your data in the serializers using conditionals in cases like this one.

If you want to do this when **creating** your model, you must override such method with something like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    if not validated_data.get('subtotal', 0):
       validated_data['status'] = # Set your OVERDUE status here
    return Your_Model(**validated_data)
```

Something similar will apply if you want to set your model status field when updating such.

I don't know if you are using DRF in your project, but I do recommend you do and see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers for more information.